# manually specifying some line numbers in verse

Tags: memoir, line-numbering, verse, linenumber

I'm typesetting a translation of some ancient Greek poetry into English, and want to have the usual verse line numbers that are generated by the verse environment in the memoir article class, but I need to be able to manually specify (a) which lines get numbered and (b) what the numbers are -- this is because I want the line numbering to track not the lines in the English but the lines in the original Greek so that, e.g., the translation of line 40 in the Greek is labeled line 40, regardless of whether it is in fact the 40th line.

I've found quite a lot of helpful things about how to set the first line number of a verse, or how often the line numbers should be incremented, but nothing about how to manually input them, but maintaining the same formatting/typesetting as the automatically generated ones.